# Prove $\lim \inf (a_n)+\lim \inf (b_n) \leq \lim \inf (a_n+b_n)$ using subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\left(a_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty},\left(b_{n}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be bounded sequences.

Prove that $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\inf}\left(a_{n}\right)+\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\inf}\left(b_{n}\right)\leq\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim\inf}\left(a_{n}+b_{n}\right)$.

I know there are diffrent ways to prove it but I was asked to prove it using the proposition:

For the given sequences there exist increasing sequence of index in $\mathbb{N}\quad\left(n_{k}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty} $ s.t. $
\left(a_{n_{k}}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty},\left(b_{n_{k}}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converge.

**Thoughts** if both $\left(a_{n_{k}}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty},\left(b_{n_{k}}\right)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ converge, I can choose them as the infimum sequences and then it easy, but how can I choose the index sequence that way?

---

I found this answer

> Set $t_n=\inf\{a_k\mid k\ge n\}$, $u_n=\inf\{b_k\mid k\ge n\}$ and $v_n=\inf\{a_k+b_k\mid k\ge n\}$.
> If $k\ge n$, then $t_n\le a_k$ and $u_n\le b_k$, so $t_n+u_n\le a_k+b_k$. Since $k$ is arbitrary, we have
> $$
> t_n+u_n\le v_n
> $$

My problem is that $t_n,u_n$ are not necessarily part of $a_n,b_n$.

Comment: You know that you can choose converging subsequence of one bounded sequence? If so, first choose subsequence from $a_n$, then from corresponding subsequence of $b_n$ (which is still bounded) choose subsubsequence. However, I don't know how it should give the statement about inf (as replacing sequence with subsequence can change infimum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$c=\liminf (a_n+b_n),\quad a=\liminf a_n,\quad   b=\liminf b_n$$ There exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}$ convergent to $c.$ Since $a_{n_k}$ is bounded, we can choose a subsequence  $a_{n_{k_l}},$ which is convergent, say to $\tilde{a}.$ Hence $\tilde{a}\ge a.$ Next as $b_{n_{k_l}}$ is bounded, we can choose a subsequence  $b_{n_{k_{l_m}}},$ which is convergent, say to $\tilde{b}.$ Then $\tilde{b}\ge b.$ Moreover $a_{n_{k_{l_m}}}\to \tilde{a}. $ Therefore
$$c=\lim_{m\to\infty}\left [a_{n_{k_{l_m}}}+b_{n_{k_{l_m}}}\right ]=\tilde{a}+\tilde{b}\ge a+b$$

Comment: Can you explain why "There exists a subsequence $a_{n_k}+b_{n_k}$ convergent to $c$"?
Why can I choose the limit to be $c$?

Comment: @G.Ticher How do you define $\liminf$ as there are several equivalent definitions ? I have used the property that for a bounded sequence $\liminf$ is the least accumulation point of the sequence. That means there is a subsequence convergent to $c$ and if another subsequence is convergent, say to $\tilde{c}$ then $\tilde{c}\ge c.$

Comment: I understand now! I thought that $a_{n{_k}}$ is also converge and I was wrong. Thank you.